# In systemverilog how to provide commandline overrides for complex fields like associative array fields

Tags: command-line, overriding, system-verilog, uvm

Lets say i have added a associative array string,string field to the factory through the macro `ovm_field_aa_string_string macro. Is there a way to configure it from command line like we do with simple int fields like follows:

```
./simv ... +ovm_set_config_int=scope,name,value
```

is there something like

```
./simv ... +ovm_set_config_aa_string_string=scope,name,key=val,key2=val2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can only set int's and strings from the command line. I strongly discourge the use of any `uvm_field macros because of their inability to deal with complex times, the the poor simulation performance they impose.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be already answered by someone else
Here is the link to the post
[how to get array of values as plusargs in systemverilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519349/how-to-get-array-of-values-as-plusargs-in-systemverilog)

Comment: That link is not relevant to this question.